# Checking if text file is properly formatted in C++

Tags: c++

How can I check that every line in the file is correctly formatted?

For example, lets say I have this text file"

```
WordOne        0.2
WordTwo        0.1
WordThree      0.38
WordFour      WordFour   <--- This would be incorrectly formatted.
```

The first word should be a string and the second should be a double. How can I properly check this?

Comment: How do I know the first three lines aren't the ones that are wrong?

Comment: because the first word in each line in a string and the second is a double.

Comment: So in pseudo-code, read a line, check against your template, accept or reject, repeat until done. I don't see a real question here.

Comment: read in the file, split each line based on a delimiter and then check making sure the first variable is a string and the next contains a double.

Comment: Probably need more detail, like, what exact characters are (or are not) allowed in the first "string"? Is it letters only, or would something like `R1ght` be allowed? If it's letters-only, that's pretty trivial. If it's "anything's allowed before the first white-space, that's trivial too--but it's impossible for use to guess which applies.

Comment: But how do I check to make sure that the 2nd word in each line is actually a double? A double could be stuck in a string but a string could not be stuck in a double and would crash the program. Not sure what's with all the negativity and down voting.

Comment: Me neither people always downvote to quickly on this site. Check out strtol: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol

Comment: "How would I solve this?": no effort shown. There are tons of possible answers: too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is best solution for your problem.

They are supported by C++11:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

auto lines = std::vector<std::string> {
    "WordOne        2",
    "WordTwo        10.1",
    "WordThree      0.38",
    "WordThree      0.",
    "WordFive      WordFive"
};

int main() {
    std::regex re("\\w+\\s+\\d+\\.?\\d*");
    for(auto line : lines) {
        if(!std::regex_match(line, re)) {
            std::cout << "Line: \"" << line
                    << "\" is incorrectly formatted" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

This code allows various forms of fractional floating point syntax. You may want to make it more strict or allow exponential forms - just modify regex :)

Comment: Absolutely exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know this existed in C++. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

if `s` is the file associated text stream, given `std::string wd; double d;`

an expression like `s >> wd >> d` will attempt to read the word and the double and evaluates as "false" (nullptr, in fact) if it fails somehow.

At that point you should reset the error flag (`s.clear()`), discard anything to "\n" and continue. ( `s.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');` )

You can count the read lines, as save the line number of the ones that makes the read failure.

Comment: Emilo, thank you for your post. I will give this a try and will vote you best answer if it was what I was needing :-)